# Excluding SPM packages from building in specific targets

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift-package-manager

Say I have some debugging library, and I want it to not be included in the production versions of my iOS app, how can I achieve this with Swift Package Manager? so in short, I want it to be only part of development builds.

Comment: The `Package.swift` file is like any other `.swift` you can include and exclude in there

Answer (score 0):

You can conditionally include a package in a target, [reference](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/main/proposals/0273-swiftpm-conditional-target-dependencies.md).

```
// swift-tools-version:5.3

import PackageDescription

let package = Package(
    name: "BestPackage",
    dependencies: [
        .package(url: "https://github.com/pureswift/bluetooth", .branch("master")),
        .package(url: "https://github.com/pureswift/bluetoothlinux", .branch("master")),
    ],
    targets: [
        .target(
            name: "BestExecutable",
            dependencies: [
                .product(name: "Bluetooth", condition: .when(platforms: [.macOS])),
                .product(name: "BluetoothLinux", condition: .when(platforms: [.linux])),
                .target(name: "DebugHelpers", condition: .when(configuration: .debug)),
            ]
        ),
        .target(name: "DebugHelpers")
     ]
)
```

Comment: I ended up excluding binaries from the build, because there is no explicit Package.swift

Comment: @DeyaEldeen how did you do it?

Comment: see this, https://github.com/FLEXTool/FLEX, search for "Be sure to exclude FLEX from Release builds or your app will be rejected".

Comment: The configuration condition was never implemented as of Swift 5.9. https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/main/proposals/0273-swiftpm-conditional-target-dependencies.md